# Seam / Hibernate - getting ORA message text

Tags: java, hibernate, seam, ora-00001

```
    try {
        if (schId != null) {
            log.info(">>> save");
            schedule = em.merge(schedule);

            em.persist(schedule);
        } else {
            em.persist(schedule);
        }

        em.flush();
        ret = "ok";
    } catch (Exception err) {
        ret = err.getMessage();
        err.printStackTrace();

        facesMessages.addFromResourceBundle(Severity.ERROR, "databaseError", ret);
    }
```

When I have duplicate key error `err.getMessage()` returns `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch`

In the stacktrace there is this error too:
`java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ACM.SCH_UK) violated`

How can I get this ORA-00001 message as a string, instead of the `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` text?

Comment: what exactly do you want to obtain? And why your code is not succeeding currently (what's the result now)?

Comment: I entered a duplicate key on purpose as test. I want to show on screen the ORA error to the user.

Comment: Have you tried using `err.getCause().getMessage()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.sql.BatchUpdateException` is the root cause of your `PersistenceException`, you can extract it as follows:

```
public static Throwable getRootCause(Throwable ex) {
    while (true) {
        Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
        if (cause == null) return ex;
        ex = cause;
    }
}
```

.

```
ret = getRootCause(ex).getMessage();
```